# Python - выбор объектов из списка с конкретным диапазоном

Tags: python, python-3.x

у меня появилась проблема, попытаюсь как можно понятнее объяснить.
И так, у меня есть список слов, допустим в нем есть "какие то слова не понятно какие но есть". И так же есть рандомное число, пусть будет 6. И со всеми этими данными мне нужно сгенерировать строку, в которой будет 6 слов из этого списка, но они будут рандомно разбросаны, то есть должно получится "слова какие есть то но есть". И если будет число 8, то в строке должно быть 8 таких слов в рандомном порядке. Как можно это реализовать? Заранее спасибо

Comment: random.shuffle(lst)     print(' '.join(lst[:amount])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random
import string

# эта функция рандомно выбирает заданное количество слов из массива со словами
def choice(word_list, number, overlap=False):
    """
    Функция принимает word_list - список со словами,
    и number - количество слов, которое нужно выбрать из списка.
    Если длина word_list будет меньше number,
    то вернётся список с той же длиной.
    Если задать значение для overlap=True и
    длина word_list будет меньше number,
    то будет возвращаться список заданной длины, но в нем будут повторения.
    Если word_list пуст, возвращается пустой список.
    """
    if len(word_list) == 0:
        return ""

    if overlap:
        return " ".join([random.choice(word_list) for _ in range(number)])
    else:
        random.shuffle(word_list)
        return " ".join(word_list[:number])


list_of_words = 'VdHf dwbWXEgsb ANuRgAyNUe RDDSATRqHjvb oFegomTG pvqqUF UEIChMkBnguNj ExG JgU eRUhtArCw KRDh'.split()


result = [
    choice(list_of_words, 3),
    choice(list_of_words, 4),
    choice(list_of_words, 10),
    choice(list_of_words, 10, True),
]

print(*result, sep="\n"*2)
```

вовод:

```
VdHf eRUhtArCw KRDh

KRDh eRUhtArCw ANuRgAyNUe dwbWXEgsb

ANuRgAyNUe JgU eRUhtArCw KRDh dwbWXEgsb ExG VdHf

KRDh eRUhtArCw JgU eRUhtArCw KRDh KRDh JgU VdHf dwbWXEgsb KRDh
```

В первом и втором случае можно увидеть, что всё довольно ожидаемо,
в третьем же случае мы видим, как работает ограничение, и нам выдается массив меньшего размера, нежели мы запросили,
в чётвёртом случае мы получаем массив нужного размера, но в нём присутствуют повторения.

Если вам не хочется, чтобы функция занимала столько места, вот вам коротка версия:

```
import random
import string

def choice(word_list, number, overlap=False):
    if len(word_list) == 0: return ""
    if overlap:
        return " ".join([random.choice(word_list) for _ in range(number)])
    else:
        random.shuffle(word_list)
        return " ".join(word_list[:number])
```

Comment: спасибо большое